# Why does android not want me to proc mounts

Tags: java, android, linux

So let me start by saying this had me pulling my hair out so bad that it almost definitely will be a stupidly simple answer (as per Murphy's laws), so please suggest anything you might assume I have already done

I am using android (7.1 armv7 on a Moto G4, to be precise, and it is my only device, so I can't test on anything else, at least not rooted, which is needed for the use case). I am writing an app that, long story short, needs to list filesystems. I decided to use /proc/mounts for that purpose.

Just before I forget, I DID try setting selinux to permissive, didn't work (although my instinct to doubt selinux the second some strange thing happened is probably due to my ignorance).

So, single threaded app, this static function gets called upon a button press.

```
private static String getProcMounts() {
    try {
        /* Forgive my Fr.. um, java */
        FileInputStream procmounts = new FileInputStream("/proc/mounts");
        BufferedReader mountsreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(procmounts));
        StringBuilder mountsbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = mountsreader.readLine()) != null) {
            mountsbuilder.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        mountsreader.close();
        procmounts.close();
        System.out.println(mountsbuilder.toString());
        return mountsbuilder.toString();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "/proc/mounts could not be read");
        return null;
    }
}
```

So I run it, and it works just fine. Okay, lemme remount /system as read write.

```
athene:/ $ su
athene:/ # mount -o remount,rw /system
athene:/ # exit
athene:/ $ grep system /proc/mounts
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
athene:/ $
```

Cool, now my app:

```
...
01-21 18:38:20.713 11037-11037/org.sudoforlunch.mountmanager I/System.out: none /config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
01-21 18:38:20.713 11037-11037/org.sudoforlunch.mountmanager I/System.out: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
01-21 18:38:20.713 11037-11037/org.sudoforlunch.mountmanager I/System.out: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata /data f2fs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,active_logs=6 0 0
...
```

Huh, that's strange (**UPDATE**: The strangeness is that it shows ro instead of rw, despite the fact the file contains rw). Must be some strange caching mechanism or something. Try again. Fail. Try restarting phone, remounting rw, fail. Try reinstalling, running in debug mode, every possible way of purging the phone, even reset the phone to factory (er, rom) defaults (including userdata), FIRST remounted the system partition, then tried running the app freshly. Fail.

Okay, this strange. Maybe it has something to do with how apps handle that file. Some kind of protection. `setenforce 0`. Nothing. How about try using one of those terminal apps, try catting the file from there. Oh sure, it works great there.

Hey, I could do that. I will spawn a process and rewrite the function as such:

```
private static String getProcMounts() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cat", "/proc/mounts"});
        BufferedReader mountsreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder mountsbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = mountsreader.readLine()) != null) {
            mountsbuilder.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        mountsreader.close();
        System.out.println(mountsbuilder.toString());
        return mountsbuilder.toString();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "/proc/mounts could not be read");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Surely this should work.

```
01-21 18:58:31.303 1149-1149/org.sudoforlunch.mountmanager I/System.out: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

No. Reset ritual, all that stuff again, made sacrifices to Cthulhu.

If you guessed from the posting time and the timestraps, yes, I have been running every one of these pieces of code verbatim again and again.

Please help.

Comment: "at least not rooted, which is needed for the use case" -- then AFAIK, [you are out of luck](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205565).

Comment: Why is the output of your application "strange"? What did you expect?

Comment: @CommonsWare well, that says I can't read it at all. This is untrue, as a) I can read it the first time, when it shows ro, and b) Selinux is setenforce 0

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it shows the mount option "ro" as opposed to "rw" which is contained in that file. I will clarify this anyway.

Comment: "well, that says I can't read it at all" -- my interpretation is that it is limited to information for your process.

Comment: @CommonsWare its /proc/mounts. Which is basically a list of filesystems and their respective mount details. I don't see how giving me an old version is relevant at all.

Comment: "its /proc/mounts" -- I am aware of this. "Which is basically a list of filesystems and their respective mount details" -- there is a lot more to `/proc/mounts` than that. Moreover, what is reported by `/proc/mounts` varies based on the UID of the process attempting to read `/proc/mounts`. That is standard Linux behavior. "I don't see how giving me an old version is relevant at all" -- from my standpoint, it is telling you that `/system` is `ro` for your process. Have you tried actually writing to somewhere in `/system` from your process? If so, did it work?

Comment: @CommonsWare ... and then it hit me. So THAT'S how proc mounts works... thanks. Anyway, I just tried and yes, spawning a su and pumping my commands into there works fine. No damage, as the app needs su to be usable anyway. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare solved this in the comments. I didn't understand the functioning of the /proc/mounts file.